# What is the derivative of the square root of a function f(x)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to figure out if the $\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{f(x)} = \frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}$
If possible can you give me the proof for the function?

Comment: This follows immediately from the power rule (writing $\sqrt{u}$  as $u^{1 / 2}$) and the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way is logarithmic differentiation $$g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$$ $$\log\big(g(x)\big)=\frac 12 \log\big(f(x)\big)$$ $$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\frac 12\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$  $$g'(x)=\frac 12\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}g(x)=\frac 12\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\sqrt{f(x)}=\frac 12\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{f(x)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

First we convert the square root to exponent notation.

$$\frac{d}{dx} \sqrt{f(x)}= \frac{d}{dx} f(x)^\frac{1}{2} $$

Then take the derivative and apply the chain rule.  That exponent is $-\frac{1}{2}$, for some reason the markup language is making it hard to see the negative sign.

$$= \frac{1}{2} f(x)^\frac{-1}{2}f'(x)$$

Converting back to notation with a square root symbol...

$$= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{f(x)}} f'(x)$$

And multiply.

$$= \frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}}$$